# Separar un string en PHP

Tags: php, html

soy novato en esto de PHP y no sé como tratar esta problemática que me ha surgido. Resulta que de un HTML leo una cadena de texto, más en concreto la información que se muestra en la imagen (1). Lo que quiero hacer es lo siguiente:

Teniendo el String "Product Code: MH-0092 Availability: In Stock", almacenar en $mpn la cadena "MH-0092" y en $avail un true porque esta "In Stock", no sé si me he explicado bien. El código lo dejo en (2)

(1)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

(2)

```
    private $mpn = '';
    private $avail = null;

    public function beforeParse() : void {
        $description = $this->getText('div#content .product-info .right .description');
        print_r($description);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aunque tu problema se puede abordar desde muchas maneras haciendo uso de muchas de las [funciones de string que tiene PHP][1], creo que la más sencilla es usando [explode][2] [de la siguiente manera][3]:

```
//String a comparar
$str = "Product Code: MH-0092 Availability: In Stock";

//Dividimos el string en un array de 5 posiciones
//Dando como resultado algo como el siguiente array
//Array(
//   [0] => Product
//   [1] => Code:
//   [2] => MH-0092
//   [3] => Availability:
//   [4] => In Stock
//);
$str = explode(' ', $str, 5);

//Conociendo la posición del código, lo almacenamos en la variable $mpn
$mpn = $str[2];

//Conociendo la posición del Stock, evalúamos 
//y almacenamos true o false, según se requiera
$avail = $str[4] === 'In Stock' ? true : false;

//Salida esperada:
//string(7) "MH-0092"
//bool(true)
var_dump($mpn, $avail);
```

Espero te sea de utilidad, en el último enlace, te dejo cómo debería funcionar el código.

Saludos.
[1]: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php
[2]: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php
[3]: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a498ce2bcf5778be0826352584e7124d6b2d7ed7

Comment: Perfectisimo, me sirvio genial! Muchas gracias

Comment: Me alegro. Recuerda marcar la pregunta como aceptada para que no se acumule como pregunta sin respuesta.